# Populate server side dropdown with folder list from specific library

Tags: 2010

I have one application page with one dropdownlist which needs to be filled with the folders from one document library

The library has this structure

```
Folder1

    Folder1.1

   Folder1.2

Folder2

    Folder2.1

       Folder2.1.1

       Folder2.1.2
```

I would like to fill a dropdown list with the folder list in a hierarchical way if possible.
It has to be server side code, not client side code.

I found something might be useful to me but it wont return the results as I want
http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-manage.html

Any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get all [subfolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.subfolders.aspx) recursively and [populate a dropdownlist with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132643/adding-listitems-to-a-dropdownlist-from-a-generic-list)

```
var dropdownList...
var list....
var folder = list.RootFolder;
PopulateDropDownList(folder);
private void PopulateDropDownList(SPFolder folder) {
  dropdownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(folder.Name, folder.UniqueId));
  foreach(var subfolder in folder.SubFolders) {
    PopulateDropDownList(subfolder); //recursively invoke each self
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this code. I have just written down what I think should work.

Comment: just perfect, I changed folder.Name with folder.Url so the user can better see the folder structure. :)

Comment: Cool that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the tree view control for something like this.

Comment: its an application page.

Comment: I'd create a custom web part for this. That way it doesn't matter what page you add it to.